# Looping and concatenating parent child node in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a xml looks like this :

```
<School>
<Class>
    <Student1>Student1</Student1>
</Class>
<Major>
    <Name1>Name1</Name1>    
    <List>
        <Title1>Title1</Title1>
    </List>
    <List>
        <Title2>Title2</Title2>
    </List>
</Major>
<Class>
    <Student2>Student2</Student2>
</Class>
<Major>
    <Name2>Name2</Name2>    
    <List>
        <Title3>Title3</Title3>
    </List>
    <List>
        <Title4>Title4</Title4>
    </List>
</Major></School>
```

The Class & Major's node have many sequences. I typed in 2 sample for each. The 1st Class will be join with the 1st Major and List node will be split by looping the Class & Major's node. It will occurs for the 2nd Class & 2nd Major and the rest.

And here's the desired output I want :

```
<School>
<Class>
    <Student1>Student1</Student1>
    <Name1>Name1</Name1>
    <List>
        <Title1>Title1</Title1>
    </List>
</Class>
<Class>
    <Student1>Student1</Student1>
    <Name1>Name1</Name1>
    <List>
        <Title2>Title2</Title2>
    </List>
</Class>    
<Class>
    <Student2>Student2</Student2>
    <Name2>Name2</Name2>
    <List>
        <Title3>Title3</Title3>
    </List>
</Class>
    <Class>
    <Student2>Student2</Student2>
    <Name2>Name2</Name2>
    <List>
        <Title4>Title4</Title4>
    </List>
</Class></School>
```

How I can transform my XML into desired output?

Comment: It looks like you forgot to include the XML code. To add XML as code, just click the "edit" button to edit the question, paste in the XML, select it and click the `{}` to format it is as code. Make sure you paste in both your input XML and expected output XML, and explain the logic of the transformation and where you are stuck with it. Thank you!

Comment: Please add your XML code

Comment: yup. I forgot to add the XML code. thank you for that.. :)

Comment: "*...and explain the logic of the transformation and where you are stuck with it.*"

Comment: join child node on Major to the Class node, so Student's & Name's node will be on Class node.
Do repetition from that joining node based on how many List's node inside the Major. and add list node to the repitition.
The first major will join to the first class, the second major will be join to the second class, and so on.
Actually, I dont know how to create a proper code for the XSLT. so, I'm stuck on it.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you want a separate `Class` element for each `Major\List` element, so one way to do this is start off by selecting `Major\List` elements

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Major/List" />
```

Then, you have a template matching `List` where you create the `Class` element and add in all the required elements. For example:

```
<xsl:template match="List">
  <Class>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../preceding-sibling::Class[1]/*" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[not(self::List)]" />
    <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
  </Class>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT. Note this assumes there is always going to be a `Major` element for each `Class` and that each `Major` will have at least one `List` present.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="School">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Major/List" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="List">
    <Class>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../preceding-sibling::Class[1]/*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[not(self::List)]" />
      <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
    </Class>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of the [Identity Template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to copy across all other nodes without changes.